# CSS Issue: <hr> line not showing in non-compatibility view in IE 8

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, styles

I am having an issue with `<hr>` in IE8 (normal view) This is my CSS styling for that:

```
#ViewName hr
{
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

I can see the horizontal lines in IE8 (compatibility mode) but not in normal mode. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Border has to be 1px minimum for hr to work in IE8.

```
#ViewName hr
{
background-color: #CCCCCC;
border: 1px;
font-size: 14pt;
}
```

This is not the issue in IE9.